# Python html2pdf bugs?

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to work out if I can use xhtml2pdf for a client project or if I need to get my hands dirty and get into ReportLab and deep dive into PDF world. I think xhtml2pdf has bugs and isn't very active as a project but I could be wrong?

Here are my immediate issues.

1) I can't get a table of content to show despite trying the documented example of created a TOC.

2) I can't get the frame borders to disappear, I can get them to lighten but not dissapear. In the doc it says use -pdf-frame-border: 1; to get frame borders for debugging. If I do not put -pdf-frame-border anywhere in markup I get big bold borders, if I do -pdf-frame-border: 1; I get the same, if I do -pdf-frame-border: 0; I get light grey borders. I even tried -pdf-frame-border: none; but that also gives me light grey. Any ideas?

My code is here.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>
{%block title%} 
{%endblock%}
</title>
<style type="text/css">
{% block style %}
    @page {
        size: a4 portrait;
        @frame header_frame {           /* Static Frame */
            -pdf-frame-content: header-content;
            left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 50pt; height: 40pt;
        }
        @frame content_frame {          /* Content Frame */
            left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 90pt; height: 662pt;
        }
        @frame footer_frame {           /* Another static Frame */
            -pdf-frame-content: footer-content;
            left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 772pt; height: 120pt;
        }



    }
    pdftoc {
        color: #666;
    }
    pdftoc.pdftoclevel0 {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 0.5em;
    }
    pdftoc.pdftoclevel1 {
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    pdftoc.pdftoclevel2 {
        margin-left: 2em;
        font-style: italic;
    }   

    img {
        width:70px;
    }

    #header-content {
        border-bottom-style:solid 1px; 
        border-bottom-color:rgb(81,192,199);
        text-align:right;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    #footer-content .divider {
        width:100%;
        border-top-style:solid 1px; 
        border-top-color:rgb(81,192,199);
    }
    #footer-content img {
        padding-left:20px;
    }
{%endblock%}    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header-content">
        Header
    </div>



    <div id="footer-content">
        <div class="divider">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="padding-left:30px;">
            <img src="/static/img/logo.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <div style="block;text-align:center;margin-top:5px;">Strictly Private and Confidential</div>
        <div style="text-align:center;">Page <pdf:pagenumber> of <pdf:pagecount> </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the block content...

```
{% extends "client/candidate_report/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{title}}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


    <h1>This is the main title of this page</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
{% endblock %}

{%block page_foot%}
    {{block.super}}
{%endblock%}
```

It doesn't matter how simple I make it, I can't get a TOC and no borders.

Comment: OK, TOC is now showing, I had to wrap it in <p>. I don't see that in the doc so hopefully that will help someone. I am now in source code trying to work out how to get rid of -pdf-frame-border. If anyone can save me that would be great!

Comment: Next issue was that I had to add a space after the <pdf:pagecount> otherwise it ends up as double numbers, i.e. page one is 11